# ImportError: No module named 'appdirs'

Tags: python, linux, server

I'm trying to get a program called [hangoutsbot](https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot)
to work on my linux server. I'm currently using a digital ocean server. However, every time I try to run the script it gives me an error that says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'appdirs'
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I've already tried installing appdirs from npm to no avail. This script works fine on my mac, however it doesn't seem to want to run on my linux server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you install it? Almost sure you are using the wrong interpreter to run the code,

Comment: I installed it by cloning the folder in a directory. When I try to run it I just use python3 hangupsbot.py

Comment: what does `which -a python3` and `which python3` output? There are also packages that are required,https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: did you try `pip3 install hangoutsbot`

Comment: which -a python3 outputs: /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3. And I have used pip3 to install it. However, when I do that it's installed in a directory I can't seem to find.

Comment: Ok, then you have two versions installed, what does `which python3` output?

Comment: Ok, which python3 shows: /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Then  try running the script with `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I get the same error when I run the script with that.

Comment: Did you use `pip` or `pip3` to install?

Comment: I used pip3 to install it.

Comment: OK run `pip3 install -U hangupsbot` and tell me where it installs

Comment: It gives me this error: "Downloading/unpacking hangoutsbot
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement hangoutsbot
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for hangoutsbot
Storing debug log for failure in /home/alex/.pip/pip.log"

Comment: That was a typo, use `hangupsbot`

Comment: Ok, now it successfully installed.

Comment: does the script work? Also where did it install, what was the path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90683/discussion-between-alex-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran across the same problem after solving the "missing pyparsing module" bug [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181056/when-i-do-pip-version-it-show-the-error-as-importerror-no-module-named-pypars).   I then started getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    import appdirs
ImportError: No module named appdirs
```

I then used the manual installation steps there to find the missing package on [pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs/1.4.3) and came up with this manual installation sequence:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/48/69/d87c60746b393309ca30761f8e2b49473d43450b150cb08f3c6df5c11be5/appdirs-1.4.3.tar.gz
gunzip appdirs-1.4.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf appdirs-1.4.3.tar
cd appdirs-1.4.3
sudo python setup.py install
```

And that fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

For some reason your `pipenv` installation is not completely done, maybe if you just uninstall and install all missing packages again, it can works. For example, if you are using a MAC:

`sudo pip uninstall <missing packages>`  and after  `sudo pip install <missing packages>`

In this specific case:

`sudo pip uninstall appdirs` and `sudo pip install appdirs`

Answer (score 0):

When you run hangoutsbot you'll need to specifically call the python version that has the modules installed. The following worked for me and I had python3.4 and python3.5 installed.

```
python3.5 hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot.py -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 14.04 , which ships with a really old version of pip.  I was using python 2.7.  Upgrading to a newer version of pip with "pip install --upgrade pip" solved this issue for me.  (I did this within my virtualenv, but could be needed at the system level depending on what you are trying to do.)

This was where I discovered the solution:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5pwngp/setuptools_34_has_been_released_and_breaks_with/
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` didn't work on my Linux Mint 18.1 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) as it refused to overwrite the system installation of pip:  running `apt-get remove python-pip` followed by [installing pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) worked for me.